# What kind of Dynamics CRM 2011 Online authentication needs to use deploy in godaddy shared server

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamic-data, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I am having an issue when I tried to deploy an application which communicates with Dynamics CRM 2011 online in godaddy shared server.
I don't have any issue when I run in my local, I am using wsdlbaseproxies online code provided in sdk\samplecode\cs\wsdlbasedproxies\online to authenticate the dynamics CRM. This process is creating LiveDeviceID.xml in the local system and failing to create the same in the godaddy shared hosting server.

This application is developed in .net which captures leads, opportunity and saves/retrieves the same in/from CRM 2011 online.

I really appreciate your help and input on this.

**Updated with error message:**

> The data protection operation was unsuccessful. This may have been caused by not having the user profile loaded for the current thread's user context, which may be the case when the thread is impersonating. 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:**

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The data protection operation was unsuccessful. This may have been caused by not having the user profile loaded for the current thread's user context, which may be the case when the thread is impersonating.

**Source Error:**

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

**Stack Trace:**

```
[CryptographicException: The data protection operation was unsuccessful. This may have been caused by not having the user profile loaded for the current thread's user context, which may be the case when the thread is impersonating.]
   System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Protect(Byte[] userData, Byte[] optionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope scope) +522
   Microsoft.Crm.Services.Utility.DeviceUserName.Encrypt(String value) in C:\Users\Aashritha\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\hcrm\hcrm\Models\DeviceidManager.cs:970
   Microsoft.Crm.Services.Utility.DeviceUserName.UpdateCredentials(String encryptedValue, String decryptedValue) in C:\Users\Aashritha\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\hcrm\hcrm\Models\DeviceidManager.cs:941
   Microsoft.Crm.Services.Utility.DeviceUserName.set_DecryptedPassword(String value) in C:\Users\Aashritha\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\hcrm\hcrm\Models\DeviceidManager.cs:897
   Microsoft.Crm.Services.Utility.DeviceIdManager.GenerateDeviceUserName() in C:\Users\Aashritha\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\hcrm\hcrm\Models\DeviceidManager.cs:462
   Microsoft.Crm.Services.Utility.DeviceIdManager.GenerateDevice(String deviceName, String devicePassword) in C:\Users\Aashritha\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\hcrm\hcrm\Models\DeviceidManager.cs:377
   Microsoft.Crm.Services.Utility.DeviceIdManager.RegisterDevice(Guid applicationId, Uri issuerUri, String deviceName, String devicePassword) in C:\Users\Aashritha\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\hcrm\hcrm\Models\DeviceidManager.cs:189
   Microsoft.Crm.Services.Utility.DeviceIdManager.LoadOrRegisterDevice(Uri issuerUri, String deviceName, String devicePassword) in C:\Users\Aashritha\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\hcrm\hcrm\Models\DeviceidManager.cs:116
   Microsoft.Crm.Services.Utility.DeviceIdManager.LoadOrRegisterDevice(Uri issuerUri) in C:\Users\Aashritha\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\hcrm\hcrm\Models\DeviceidManager.cs:99
   Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Samples.WsdlTokenManager.Authenticate(ClientCredentials credentials, String appliesTo, String policy, Uri issuerUri) in C:\Users\Aashritha\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\hcrm\hcrm\Models\WsdlTokenManager.cs:141
   CRMDynamicsService.CRMDynamicsOnline.Authenticate(LiveIdAuthenticationPolicy policy, String userName, String password) in C:\Users\Aashritha\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\hcrm\hcrm\Models\CRMDynamicsService.cs:262
   CRMDynamicsService.CRMDynamicsOnline.GetLeads() in C:\Users\Aashritha\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\hcrm\hcrm\Models\CRMDynamicsService.cs:420
   hcrm.Controllers.LeadsController.Leads() in C:\Users\Aashritha\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\hcrm\hcrm\Controllers\LeadsController.cs:20
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +208
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +263
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +191
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +343
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8970061
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

Comment: Please provins more information abort how the server startup fails  (error message, logs, etc).

Comment: Please check the error message, updated in the post

Comment: I'm assuming this is an ASP.NET application. If so, what AppPool is it running under and what account is that AppPool running under?

Comment: AppPool is running under integrated mode